# Parallel For-Loop

Tags: for-loop, concurrency, go

I want the for-loop to be parallel using go routines. i tried using channels but that didnt work. My main problem is, that i want to wait for all iterations to be finished before continuing. That's why simply writing `go` before it doesn't work. I tried to using channels (i think the wrong way) but that made my code even slower

```
func createPopulation(populationSize int, individualSize int) []Individual {
    population := make([]Individual, populationSize)

    //i want this loop to be work parallel
    for i := 0; i < len(population); i++ {
        population[i] = createIndividual(individualSize)
    }

    return population
}

func createIndividual(size int) Individual {
    var individual = Individual{make([]bool, size), 0}

    for i := 0; i < len(individual.gene); i++ {
        if rand.Intn(2)%2 == 1 {
            individual.gene[i] = true
        } else {
            individual.gene[i] = false
        }
    }

    return individual
}
```

My struct looks like this:

```
type Individual struct {
    gene []bool
    fitness int
}
```

Comment: have you set the env variable GOMAXPROCS when trying the different versions out ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So basically the goroutine should not return a value but push it down a channel. If you want to wait for all goroutines to finish you can just count to the number of goroutines, or use a WaitGroup. In this example it's an overkill because the size is known, but it's good practice anyway. Here's a modified example:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

type Individual struct {
    gene    []bool
    fitness int
}


func createPopulation(populationSize int, individualSize int) []Individual  {

    // we create a slice with a capacity of populationSize but 0 size
    // so we'll avoid extra unneeded allocations
    population := make([]Individual, 0, populationSize)

    // we create a buffered channel so writing to it won't block while we wait for the waitgroup to finish
    ch := make(chan Individual, populationSize)

    // we create a waitgroup - basically block until N tasks say they are done
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < populationSize; i++ {

        //we add 1 to the wait group - each worker will decrease it back
        wg.Add(1)

        //now we spawn a goroutine
        go createIndividual(individualSize, ch, &wg)
    }

    // now we wait for everyone to finish - again, not a must.
    // you can just receive from the channel N times, and use a timeout or something for safety
    wg.Wait()

    // we need to close the channel or the following loop will get stuck
    close(ch)

    // we iterate over the closed channel and receive all data from it
    for individual := range ch {

        population = append(population, individual)
    }
    return population

}   

func createIndividual(size int, ch chan Individual, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    var individual = Individual{make([]bool, size), 0}

    for i := 0; i < len(individual.gene); i++ {
        if rand.Intn(2)%2 == 1 {
            individual.gene[i] = true
        } else {
            individual.gene[i] = false
        }
    }

    // push the population object down the channel
    ch <- individual
    // let the wait group know we finished
    wg.Done()

}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I have a feeling that `population := make([]Individual, populationSize)` should probably be `population := make([]Individual, 0)` in this example, otherwise the `append` statement puts the new Individuals on the end of an empty slice of length `populationSize`. http://play.golang.org/p/6eYlk40Oal

Comment: @Intermernet you're right, I missed that. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Fixed to allocating a slice with the known *capacity* but only 0 members.

Comment: this seems to work, but it's not faster on a quad core (in fact: it's slower). can you tell me why?

Comment: @PhilippSander yes. 1. You need to call `runtime.GOMAXPROC()` to the desired number of CPUs. 2. Channels and spawning goroutines have big overheads. Unless the task for each goroutine is long running, you won't see a gain.

Comment: i did that. didnt help. max is 4

Comment: so it seems like the channel overhead is larger than the time you spend in the function itself.

Comment: i'll try to verfy that. thanks for your answer so far!

Comment: Rather than calling done inside `createIndividual()` we can call it in `createPopulation` itself, after the call to `createIndividual()`. This will make the code more readable, and the responsibility remains in `createPopulation()` function itself. I didn't see `wg.Done()` being marked, and faced issue in my code, later realized that I missed to the see the code inside `createIndividual()` which has `Done()` call

Answer (score 6):

For your specific problem you don't need to use channels at all.

However unless your `createIndividual` spends some time doing calculations, the context switches between the goroutines is always gonna be much slower when run in parallel.

```
type Individual struct {
    gene    []bool
    fitness int
}

func createPopulation(populationSize int, individualSize int) (population []*Individual) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    population = make([]*Individual, populationSize)

    wg.Add(populationSize)
    for i := 0; i < populationSize; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            population[i] = createIndividual(individualSize)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return
}

func createIndividual(size int) *Individual {
    individual := &Individual{make([]bool, size), 0}

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        individual.gene[i] = rand.Intn(2)%2 == 1
    }

    return individual
}

func main() {
    numcpu := flag.Int("cpu", runtime.NumCPU(), "")
    flag.Parse()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(*numcpu)
    pop := createPopulation(1e2, 21e3)
    fmt.Println(len(pop))
}
```

Output:

```
┌─ oneofone@Oa [/tmp]                                                                                                            
└──➜ go build blah.go; xtime ./blah -cpu 1
100
0.13u 0.00s 0.13r 4556kB ./blah -cpu 1
┌─ oneofone@Oa [/tmp]                                                                                                            
└──➜ go build blah.go; xtime ./blah -cpu 4
100
2.10u 0.12s 0.60r 4724kB ./blah -cpu 4
```

Answer (score 3):

One common way to add controlled parallelism to a loop like this is to spawn a number of worker goroutines that will read tasks from a channel.  The [`runtime.NumCPU`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumCPU) function may help in deciding how many workers it makes sense to spawn (make sure you set [`GOMAXPROCS`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) appropriately to take advantage of those CPUs though).  You then simply write the jobs to the channel and they will be handled by the workers.

In this case where the job is to initialise elements of the population slice, so using a channel of `*Individual` pointers might make sense.  Something like this:

```
ch := make(chan *Individual)
for i := 0; i < nworkers; i++ {
    go initIndividuals(individualSize, ch)
}

population := make([]Individual, populationSize)
for i := 0; i < len(population); i++ {
    ch <- &population[i]
}
close(ch)
```

The worker goroutine would look something like this:

```
func initIndividuals(size int, ch <-chan *Individual) {
    for individual := range ch {
        // Or alternatively inline the createIndividual() code here if it is the only call
        *individual = createIndividual(size)
    }
}
```

Since tasks are not portioned out ahead of time, it doesn't matter if `createIndividual` takes a variable amount of time: each worker will only take on a new task when the last is complete, and will exit when there are no tasks left (since the channel is closed at that point).

But how do we know when the job has completed?  The [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) type can help here.  The code to spawn the worker goroutines can be modified like so:

```
ch := make(chan *Individual)
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(nworkers)
for i := 0; i < nworkers; i++ {
    go initIndividuals(individualSize, ch, &wg)
}
```

The `initIndividuals` function is also modified to take the additional parameter, and add `defer wg.Done()` as the first statement.  Now a call to `wg.Wait()` will block until all the worker goroutines have completed.  You can then return the fully constructed `population` slice.

Comment: `for i := 9; i < nworkers; i++ {` why do you init i with 9? whats nworkers?

Comment: `nworkers` is the number of worker goroutines you want to spawn.  Each worker will handle multiple tasks, so it should be `GOMAXPROCS` (for maximum parallelism) rather than the total number of tasks.

Comment: `for i := 0; i < nworkers; i++ {` then this doesnt make any sense

Comment: What part doesn't make sense to you?  It is a loop to spawn a number of worker goroutines to reach the desired level of parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know beforehand how many individuals you will have, I would refrain from using channels and just assign the individual members of `population` in the goroutine `createIndividual`. The signature of `createIndividual` would then look like this:

```
func createIndividual(wg *sync.WaitGroup, individual *Individual, size int)
```

and the calling code would look like this:

```
population := make([]Individual, populationSize)
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(len(population))

for i := 0; i < len(population); i++ {
    go createIndividual(wg, &population[i], individualSize)
}

wg.Wait()
```

So, each go routine is responsible for exactly one individual, which it assigns to the corresponding slot in `population`:

```
func createIndividual(wg *sync.WaitGroup, individual *Individual, size int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    *individual = Individual{make([]bool, size), 0}

    // assign other attributes to `individual`
}
```

You can see a complete code example [on play here](http://play.golang.org/p/iQCzi5fgzD).

Comment: This will certainly work, but one might argue that it goes against Go's "share memory by communicating" idiom.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Yes, but since this seems to be a very small and isolated problem I would argue that it is fine to do this for the sake of performance and readability. But of course this all depends on what `createIndividual` will do in the end. It might turn out that the channel solution is actually faster in the end.

Comment: I'm not even sure, since all this stuff is 100% CPU and very quick (per goroutine), that doing it in parallel will be faster than doing it in a single loop. Depends on the "individual size" I guess. Not having channels has a big performance effect, but you know, that's how stuff like Heartbleed is born :)

Comment: Oh come on, this solution is actually *more* readable and understandable than the channel solution (less code, less abstraction) so I could argue that using channels in this case is what makes 'stuff like Heartbleed' happen. That argument is misplaced.

Comment: the only problem with it is that you are passing around pointers to locations in a pre-allocated array. When the code grows more complicated the chances of race conditions and stepping on pointers increase. The isolation that channels provide prevents this. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to avoid mixing concurrency logic with business logic, I wrote this library https://github.com/shomali11/parallelizer to help you with that. It encapsulates the concurrency logic so you do not have to worry about it.

So in your example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/shomali11/parallelizer"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    populationSize := 100
    results = make([]*Individual, populationSize)

    options := &Options{ Timeout: time.Second }
    group := parallelizer.NewGroup(options)
    for i := 0; i < populationSize; i++ {
        group.Add(func(index int, results *[]*Individual) {
            return func () {
                ...

                results[index] = &Individual{...}
            }
        }(i, &results))
    }

    err := group.Run()

    fmt.Println("Done")
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Results: %v", results))
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err) // nil if it completed, err if timed out
}
```